# Converting a bean to Map with Jackson recursively

Tags: scala, jackson

I am trying to get a json from a bean (it's properties). Using Jackson, I managed to get a Map, but the conversion doesn't seem to be recursive.

My beans has nested beans, so the following code:

```
val m = new ObjectMapper()
val mapType: MapType = m.getTypeFactory.constructMapType(classOf[java.util.Map[_, _]], classOf[String], classOf[Any])
val map = mapAsScalaMapConverter(m.convertValue(bean, mapType).asInstanceOf[java.util.HashMap[String, Any]])
println(map.asScala.toMap)
```

prints:

```
Map(
    propertyOne -> true,
    propertyTwo -> false,
    propertyThree -> [],
    propertyWithBean -> {
        propertyOne=false,
        propertyTwo=0,
    },
    propertyFour -> blah
)
```

As you can see, this isn't converting to a map the nested bean `propertyWithBean`, which then, when using `scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject(map.asScala.toMap)` doesn't output a valid JSON.

Is there a way to do the mapper.convertValue recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the bean to a `Map` in a fully recursive way
with method [`convertValue(Object, Class)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class)) of class `ObjectMapper`:

```
val m = new ObjectMapper()
val map = m.convertValue(bean, classOf[java.util.Map[_, _]])
```

Then the map can be printed as JSON by:

```
println(m.writeValueAsString(bean))
```